# Unpack a list to cycle tag in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know, I can do something like

```
{% cycle "value1" "value2" %}
```

But what if I have all my input values in a list. Can I do something like?

```
{% cycle my_input_list %}
```

Answer (score 5):

The built in django cycle tag does not support passing in variables.
You can make your own custom tag though.
Something like this should work:

```
import itertools
from django import template
register = template.Library()


class CycleNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, cyclevars):
        self.cyclevars = template.Variable(cyclevars)

    def render(self, context):
        names = self.cyclevars.resolve(context)
        if self not in context.render_context:
            context.render_context[self] = itertools.cycle(names)
        cycle_iter = context.render_context[self]
        return next(cycle_iter)


@register.tag
def cycle_list(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, arg = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            "%r tag requires an argument" % token.contents.split()[0]
        )
    node = CycleNode(arg)
    return node
```

And then in the template:

```
{% cycle_list some_list %}
```

Comment: Huh. So I have to rewrite the code for any such tag. I just have cycle tag as an example here. I have bunch of other third party tags like that and I want to unpack a list for all of them. Rewriting every tag with a new name seems bad design. I am surprised the django designers never thought about such a basic use case.

Comment: It's not the case for every tag, I'm referring to the cycle tag in particular. Take in on a case by case basis. The built in django tags cover the most common scenarios, rest is up to you.